# Directive for Document Status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a simple directive that would indicate the status of the document. I have this thing up and running through the controller and without the directive. But i want to create a reusable directive.

[image: Document Status Changed to Unsaved]

[image: Document Status New]

It would have the following states:

> 1- New:     2- Unsaved  3- Draft    4- Posted

I have created this Plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sNoHGh4c4dgYycoDAhLQ?p=preview

My directive would stay outside the form. So is there any way i could access its state from directive like this:

```
$scope.mainform.$setSubmitted();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the directive, publish the function on a scope variable defined by an attribute.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('once', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
        //publish API 
        onceAPI: '=once'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.onceAPI = scope.onceAPI || {};
        //publish function
        scope.onceAPI.setPostComplete = function() {
            console.log("post complete")
            scope.onceAPI.isPosted = true;
        }
    }
  };
});
```

USAGE

```
<div once="vm.onceAPI"></div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
vm.submit = function(){
  $scope.mainform.$setSubmitted();
  var postData = {in1: vm.in1};
  $http.post(url,postData).then(function() {
      vm.onceAPI.setPostComplete();
  });
};
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/toFjcYkis71QV8FCeFr1?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot @georgeawg. I was looking for a way to include all the functionality (including the template ) inside my directive, so that keeping the name of the form same, i could reuse it in other pages.

Comment: Can u help me with that?

Comment: What have you tried and what problems have you had? For general information on directives, visit [AngularJS Developers Guide -- Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api).

Comment: Ok @georgeawg i have read it. And from my prior experience i gathered that in order to access form properties inside my directive, i would have to give it as a dependency to my directive. As such:

require: ^form and then in my link function i would access it as:

link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl){
}

Comment: But since my directive would not be child of my form, i can't access its properties. One way would be to create another directive to know the form status such as pristine, dirty etc. 

But if you can guide me how to achieve that in workable manner, that would be quite helpful. Thanx